# how to play mp3 streaming in objectives c

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming

I have this stream url with mp3 type: http://www.slobodnyvysielac.sk/redata/other/play.php?file=informacna%20vojna%20-%202015-02-17%20financne%20skupiny.mp3

when I open this url with Safari or Chrome, it can play, but I can't play it with objectives C code (iOS).

Please tell me the solution!
Thanks all!

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[player play];

Comment: Your link contains a flash player, which is internally playing some server side mp3 file. As iOS doesn't support flash this will not work on iOS webView.

Answer (score 2):

```
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://archive.slobodnyvysielac.sk/informacna%20vojna%20-%202015-02-10%20hudo.mp3"]];
[player play];
```

Inside your view controller or whatever class you have define this, don't define it inside the event where you stream.

```
AVPlayer *player
```

EDIT:

There was a problem with your URL, if you open it in the browser, it opens a flash player so I inspected the flash object and got the original MP3 url which will stream, and you can compare how Google Chrome e.g. reacts to both URLs to notice the difference, now the url in my above code is the correct one

Comment: can't play @Aubada Taljo

Comment: should check with urlString is: http://www.slobodnyvysielac.sk/redata/other/play.php?file=informacna%20vojna%20-%202015-02-10%20hudo.mp3 . it doesn't work

Comment: I edited the answer, there was a problem with your URL

Comment: Would you please mark it as an answer as I tested it and it works (of course if it works for you)